# Why does the Python function not return the expected representation of the Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, generator, yield, convergence

I calculate the root search function in the `dichotomy()` equation using the dichotomy method and then output the values using the `print_dichotomy()` decorator. I believe that in the end I will see the columns **root - the value of the function at the root - error - convergence**. However, in fact, I get it so that only *the root* and *the value of the function* are expected to be output from the columns, and the other two columns are incorrect. In them, the error is represented by only one value (the remaining rows are `NaN`), and *the convergence* - all its values were in one row.

I did not describe the essence of the `dichotomy()` function, placing lists of pseudo-values for Pandas columns in it.

What is the mistake?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):
        *res, func, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))
        func = list(map(lambda x: f'{f(x):.10f}', res))
        result_table = pd.DataFrame()
        result_table['Roots'] = pd.Series(res)
        result_table['Function values'] = pd.Series(func)
        result_table['Calculation error'] = pd.Series(eps_list)
        result_table['Convergence'] = pd.Series(prev_roots)
        print(result_table)
    return wrapper

def f(x):
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4 * np.cos(2 * x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):

    # 1. creating a list variable to store the root values
    prev_roots = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
    # 2. let's create a list for storing calculation errors
    eps_list = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
    # 3. create a list to store the roots
    roots = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
    for root in roots:
        yield root
    yield eps_list, prev_roots
      
    # 5. we return the value of the error in calculating the root, convergence 
    yield eps_list, prev_roots

dichotomy(0.0001, 50, 0.000001, 0.000001)
```

Comment: We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)